# How do I render cms/static blocks in an attribute

Tags: magento

So I have a store and I created an attribute (text-area) called 'Downloads'

Many products use the same content for this attribute so I wanted to create a cms/static block to show the content, so I wouldn't have to change each individual product if there was a change to the 'Downloads' section.

So I made a static block called 'downloads-block' and entered my html into the content.

I put {{block type="cms/block" block_id="downloads-block"}} into the text area 'Downloads Attribute' but it doesn't render the html, it simply displays "{{block type="cms/block" block_id="test-block"}}" in plain text.

How do I get it to render the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render the block in the product description. You'll need to add it/edit into catalog/product/view.phtml.

We use this for dropshipped items. Since they don't ship from our one warehouse location it can sometimes change when the product gets delivered:

```
if ($this->isProductDropshipped()) {
$this->addShippingMessage("This item available <strong>online only</strong>. <strong><a href=\"/dropshipped\">Details</a></strong>");
```